# How to close Google Bitnami Subversion?

Tags: svn, bitnami

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R05AJ.jpg)I create new user account via google bitnami subversion. After that, i return back to main view via 'esc > q!'

After that how can i close google bitnami subversion?
Is there any command for it? Or do i need to just click close button on the top right side of corner?

Comment: I am afraid I do not fully understand your question. Could you provide some screenshots to better understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: I am so sorry reply! I attached screenshot! By the way, thank you for your concern so much!